# Need to autoincrement directory names but by avoiding some letters in the name

Tags: linux, bash, perl

My script creates a set of directories aa, ab, ac, and so on

This script autoincrement directory names but I want to avoid the letters: I, O, P, Q, R, W while creating directories.

The script which I have contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
path='/tmp/ab' 
dir_name=ls -lrt | tail -1 
export dir_name 
new_name=perl -e 'print ++$ENV{dir_name}' 
mkdir -p $new_name
```

Please suggest the changes.

Comment: Seems like a homework question. Is it?
What's your use case for this?

Comment: Why using a bash script? Why not doing all with Perl?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen need to place artifacts in these directories but the only criteria are directories name should not contain letters i,o,p,q,r,w

Comment: @Toto someone suggested me to make use of an array and then increment but I'm not good at perl. If you can please help on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s an awk script that allows you to generate the AA, AB, AC, AD, AE,
AF, AG, AH, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AS, AT, AU, AV, AX, AY, AZ, BA, … sequence
(taking the place of the perl one-liner you have):

```
awk ' BEGIN {
                alphabet = ""
                for (ind = 1; ind <= 26; ind++) {
                        letter = substr("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", ind, 1)
                        if (index("IOPQRW", letter) == 0) alphabet = alphabet letter
                }
                alphalen = length(alphabet)
        }
    NF != 1  ||  $1 ~ "[^" alphabet "]" {
                print "bad input" > "/dev/stderr"
                exit
        }
        {
                word = $1
                Len  = length(word)
                for (i = Len; i >= 1; i--) {
                        letter = substr(word, i, 1)
                        val = index(alphabet, letter)
                        if (val <= 0  ||  val > alphalen) {
                                print "This should never happen." > "/dev/stderr"
                                exit
                        }
                        carry = 0
                        if (val == alphalen) {
                                val = 0
                                carry = 1
                        }
                        letter = substr(alphabet, val+1, 1)
                        word = substr(word, 1, i-1) letter substr(word, i+1, Len)
                        if (!carry) break
                }
                if (carry) word = substr(alphabet, 1, 1) word
                print word
        } '
```

The `BEGIN` section builds the ABCDEFGHJKLMNSTUVXYZ alphabet dynamically. 
You could just say

```
                alphabet = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNSTUVXYZ"
```

The above code lets you specify the letters you want to exclude. 
The “bad input” block rejects blank input, multiple words,
and words with excluded characters.

The main block loops through the given word from right to left,
doing the same things you would do
when adding 1 to a multi-digit decimal number:

- If you have the maximum symbol value
  (‘9’ for decimal, ‘Z’ for your scheme),
  replace it with the lowest symbol and move to the left,
- otherwise, replace the symbol with the next higher symbol and stop. 
  Because of the `alphabet` we have, the next higher symbol after `H` is `J`,
  the next higher symbol after `N` is `S`,
  and the next higher symbol after `V` is `X`.
- If you get to the beginning of the word without “finishing”,
  prepend an `A`. 
  For example, `ZZ` becomes `AA` which then becomes `AAA`.

So, if you have a name in `dir_name`, you can get the next name
with

```
new_name=$(echo "$dir_name" | awk '(the above script)')
```

You can probably get rid of the “This should never happen.” error test. 
I don’t know any way that that error could happen; I just like to be safe. 
You can get rid of the “bad input” error test if you’re absolutely sure
that your shell script will never pass invalid data to the awk script.